# Declaring inner class static right decision for web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, class

Question is : Declairing inner class static makes all other instances inner class data member's data same ?

My Class definition is below where I have declared my inner class static.

My Application is using Spring boot, so every api call will create new thread .

```css
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ParentClass{

    @JsonProperty("InnerClass")
    private InnerClass innerclass;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public static class InnerClass{
        private String uniqueRequestId;
        private String transactionRequestId;
        private String batchNo;
        private String transactionRefNo;
        private String corporateCode;
    }

}`
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You should Google a bit and find out what `static` does on inner classes. Then you can answer your question. Spoiler: Does the inner class need a reference to the outer class?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you have space between Parent and Class, it's not appropriate. Also not sure if you place @JsonProperty correctly on the class level, it depends on what exactly you are planning to achieve by placing it this way. Otherwise, I don't see any problems in this implementation. You should avoid declaring an inner static class if its instance needs to access non-static fields or methods of the outer class. In your implementation, it seems like InnerClass doesn't need to access any non-static members of ParentClass, so making it static shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I Just want to make sure that inner static class members data wont become same for every other instance, bcz that would be a big issue.

Comment: The static keyword in the context of an inner class means that the class does not have a reference to an instance of the outer class. It does not mean that the fields of the inner class are static.

In other words, each instance of a static inner class has its own copies of the instance variables defined in the class. If you create two instances of InnerClass and modify the fields of one, it will not affect the other.